# get month name from timestamp column postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I wanna get the number of loans per month but I can't find a way to change the timestamp to month name, I get an error every time...

Here is the table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcCpa.png)

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for the English name of the month, you can get it from your timestamp using `to_char`:

```sql
SELECT to_char(created, 'Month')
```

This is what it looks like for today:

```sql
SELECT to_char(now(), 'Month') as month;
   month
-----------
 March
(1 row)
```